# Making a DotPlot with colored sidebars correlating to clusters and gene expression

Tags: r, ggplot2, seurat

I wanted to produce a DotPlot that adds an extra feature for linking the feature genes to the clusters they were taken from.

I can easily produce the standard DotPlot with dittoDotPlot:

```
p1 <- dittoDotPlot(Liver, top10_filter$gene, group.by = "DefClustering") + coord_flip() + theme(axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(colour = my_palette_Rui_colors))
```

[image]

And I found a website (https://davemcg.github.io/post/lets-plot-scrna-dotplots/#lets-glue-them-together-with-cowplot) where they tried adding labels, in this case relaing cluster with CellType (I want to associate gene with CellType instead)

```
labels <- ggplot(gene_cluster %>% 
                   mutate(`Cell Type` = Group,
                           cluster = factor(cluster, levels = v_clust$labels[v_clust$order])), 
                 aes(x = cluster, y = 1, fill = `Cell Type`)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1') + 
  theme_nothing() +
  xlim2(dotplot)
```

[image]

Right now I have produced this table that can easily correlate each gene to the cluster I am interested in.

```
head(top10_filter)
# A tibble: 6 × 7
# Groups:   gene [6]
      p_val avg_log2FC pct.1 pct.2 p_val_adj cluster  gene  
      <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>    <chr> 
1 0               3.19 0.957 0.004 0         Arteries GJA5  
2 0               1.83 0.783 0.005 0         Arteries LMO7  
3 1.42e-303       2.73 0.652 0.003 4.59e-299 Arteries COL8A1
4 1.72e-282       2.67 0.783 0.006 5.56e-278 Arteries SDC1  
5 1.63e-262       3.11 0.522 0.002 5.26e-258 Arteries NPR3  
6 1.76e-228       2.68 0.826 0.01  5.69e-224 Arteries NRG1
```

So how can I work with ggplot so I can get the plot I am aiming to get? right now I can produce the bar on the right handside but the colors in no way correlate to each cluster, they have been assigned proportionally.

```
labels <- ggplot( top10_filter %>% 
                   mutate(cluster,
                          ), 
                 aes(x = 1, y = cluster, fill = top10_filter$cluster), color = my_palette_Rui_colors) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  theme_nothing() +
  xlim2(p1)

p1 + labels
```

[image]

I do not fully get how the correlation between clusters and cell types was done in the example, and maybe it cannot be done the same way between genes and clusters in mine. Either way I do not know how to move forward. Thanks in advance!

Comment: check http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/, especially chapter 11 "colors".

Answer (score 1):

I think you where on the right track with geom_tile. You just have to define the desired aesthetics there as well.

Below I included a minimal example using the mtcars data set. Not the prettiest, but I hope it shows the idea.

You just have to make sure your x variable is character- or factor-type.

If you want your geom_tile on the right side of the plot, but before the legend, you can use the trick with "x = length(unique(data_tmp$cyl))+1"

```
data_tmp <- mtcars
data_tmp$type <- rownames(data_tmp)
data_tmp$cyl <- paste0(data_tmp$cyl, "_cylinder")

#type = gene
#cyl = cluster
color <- data_tmp$cyl
plot <- ggplot(data_tmp, aes(y=type, x=cyl)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=drat, color = qsec)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(y=type, x = length(unique(data_tmp$cyl))+1, fill = cyl)) + # creates a bar on the rights side of your data, coloured by your x-variable
  scale_fill_manual(values=rainbow(8)) + 
  theme_classic()

plot
```

[image]

To define colours, instead of rainbow(x), you could also use a named vector such as:

```
colours_used <- c("cluster1" = "red", "cluster2" = "blue", "cluster3" = "green")
```